# simplified 'logical' models to cleanly access highly normalized database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I know that one way to add/edit/delete (nested) records using a form is by using :accepts_nested_attributes_for: in the the corresponding models. However, when this nesting extends to about 4 levels (because of the normalization of the database), and I want to display all of these levels for editing on the website, this method seems to be rather cumbersome (and ugly).

I was wondering whether there is a way to define 'super' models with getter and setter methods that allow me to edit the necessary data in one place . As a simplified example, consider:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age

  has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street, :zip, :country

  belongs_to :person
end
```

I would like to show/edit/update/etc the name, age, street, zip, country in one form. It's clear how to do this using accepts_nested_attributes_for. But I would like to have a class, say, PersonalInformation, that combines the fields name, age, street, zip, country from both classes by passing in the id from Person. I would then like to use this class as an interface for the website.

Answer (score 1):

Something like a Form Object as described here:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects

I've been trying various implementations and haven't found the perfect solution but they do simplify "bringing a bunch of models together". The codeclimate blog also touches on it (item #3) at:

http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models

The codeclimate post uses an older method of including the ActiveModel modules (no need to include them individually unless you want to now) but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [simple form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem.  I modified an example from their docs to reflect your models that does exactly what you want:

**Models:**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age

  has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street, :zip, :country

  belongs_to :person
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :age %>
  <%= f.association :street %>
  <%= f.association :zip %>
  <%= f.association :country %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: As far as I know, f.association to does not support has_one associations. I also know how to get this to work with simple_form and multiple nested associations of varying type. But I do not want to think all the time about how the database is organized. I would like to create new models that give me a nice interface to the physical models that represent the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use virtual attributes on the Person model and put custom assignment logic within the getters/setters for each of the editable `Address` attributes.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age

  has_one :address

  def street=(new_street)
    # ...
  end
end
```

This would likely end up being more complex in the long run.